# Display not fully loading with Linux mint 17.1

Tags: boot, display, linux-mint, x-server

I've been trying to fix this problem for a couple of days. I've been through numerous debugging threads.

With Linux mint:
The login screen graphics load. After logging in to a graphical terminal, the screen is black except for the mouse, which I can move. In a text terminal, I tried:

```
$ xrandr -q
$ xrandr -d :0 --auto
$ xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS1 --auto
```

Each time the output is:

> Can't open display
>
> $ glxinfo Error: unable to open display.
>
> $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver* ... E: Unable to correct
>   problems, you have held broken packages.

Moving the monitors.XML file in the `~/.config` dir doesn't help.

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` doesn't change anything.

The mdm (mint display manager) stops and starts. Reconfiguring mdm doesn't help. I couldn't figure out how to reconfigure xorg and xserver.

From grub:
Editing the boot option.
Adding `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0` doesn't help.

With Windows 10:
I am brought to the recovery screen. Attempts to clean or check filesystems results in the system hanging. Attempts to forgo this sometimes results in correct booting.